# Can not install Net::SSH2 module Perl

Tags: ssh, debian, perl

I am getting the following log while trying to install Net::SSH2 module in my debian machine. I don have libssh2-dev installed but still Im getting this error. also it says "Couldn't find your C compiler". Im pretty sure I do have C compiler installed. how do I fix this ?

```
cpan Net::SSH2
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 07 Jan 2015 22:53:20 GMT
Running install for module 'Net::SSH2'
CPAN: Data::Dumper loaded ok (v2.124)
'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs '/root/.cpan/prefs'
Running make for R/RK/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.02)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RK/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.52)
Net-SSH2-0.53/
Net-SSH2-0.53/.gitignore
Net-SSH2-0.53/BUILDING.WIN32
Net-SSH2-0.53/Changes
Net-SSH2-0.53/example/
Net-SSH2-0.53/fallback/
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/
Net-SSH2-0.53/Makefile.PL
Net-SSH2-0.53/MANIFEST
Net-SSH2-0.53/MANIFEST.SKIP
Net-SSH2-0.53/META.yml
Net-SSH2-0.53/MYMETA.json
Net-SSH2-0.53/MYMETA.yml
Net-SSH2-0.53/ppport.h
Net-SSH2-0.53/README
Net-SSH2-0.53/SSH2.xs
Net-SSH2-0.53/t/
Net-SSH2-0.53/TODO
Net-SSH2-0.53/typemap
Net-SSH2-0.53/t/Net-SSH2.t
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/Channel.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/Dir.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/File.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/Listener.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/PublicKey.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/SFTP.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Devel/
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm
Net-SSH2-0.53/fallback/const-c.inc
Net-SSH2-0.53/fallback/const-xs.inc
Net-SSH2-0.53/example/read.pl
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build R/RK/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53.tar.gz

Subroutine checklibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 11.
Subroutine assertlibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 25.
Subroutine _author_side redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 39.

The libssh2 library is required by this module.  If you don't have it, you can
download it from http://www.libssh2.org; you may also need OpenSSL, which can
be obtained from http://www.openssl.org , or libgcrypt, which can be obtained
from http://www.gnupg.org .

Debian:   sudo aptitude install libssh2-1-dev
OpenSUSE: sudo zypper in libssh2-1 libssh2-devel

You can pass your libssh2 lib and include dirs (and extra link args) on the
command line. E.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL lib=$HOME/libssh2/lib inc=$HOME/libssh2/include \
        ldargs="-lz"

These can also be set through the LIBSSH2_LIB/LIBSSH2_INCLUDE/LIBSSH2_LDARGS
environment variables.

To build with libgcrypt instead of OpenSSL, pass 'gcrypt' as a parameter to
Makefile.PL, e.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL gcrypt

If you want to build on Windows, see the file BUILDING.WIN32 in the
distribution.

Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 17.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/Net-SSH2-0.53-S94ijz/MYMETA.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Comment: Installing through the package manager is typically recommended...

Answer (score 1):

As you say you are on Debian the easiest way is

```
aptitude install libnet-ssh2-perl
```

But if you really really wish to install it from CPAN instead make sure you've got all the development tools and libraries and also the SSH library installed:

```
aptitude install build-essential libssh2-1-dev
```

The you can install the module from CPAN - just verified on a minimal Debian installation with the above steps.